# Product page modification for specific products

Tags: magento2, product, layout, blocks, custom-options

I would like to make some product modifcations; change qty position to move in the top, add total price (qte* unit_price) in /vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/templates/product/price/amount/default.phtml.
The problem is that the block is modified in the catalog page also.
I need to make some change to the custom options block also.
So my question how to make those changes for specific products only (i can add a product attribute for that)
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Suggestion: You can solve your issue if you'll apply this method**

Add custom.phtml template file in catalog_product_view.xml

Now in custom.phtml you can use if else condition.

Add design both layout according to condition If product id is ( show your custom layout ) else (default).

Comment: can you give an example ?